# Python 2.7 Only numbers as input, the ValueError issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, numbers

How do i stop python from giving me an ValueError everytime I put a letter in? Input must be a number! Using Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `input()`, use [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), which returns a string.

[`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())` in Python 2.7. Hence, if you input a letter (let's say `'a'`), it will try look for a variable called `'a'`. If there isn't one, a `NameError` is raised.

if you're working with numbers, then you can always call `int()` on the input received by using `raw_input()`. You could also use a `try: except:` structure to catch any `ValueErrors` incase the input is not a number.